# How to write an EasyNetQ auto subscriber dispatcher for the ASP.NET Core services provider?

Tags: asp.net-core, easynetq

So, the EasyNetQ auto subscriber has a basic default dispatcher that cannot create message consumer classes with non-parameterless constructors.

To see that in action, create a consumer with a required dependency. You can setup your own service or you can use `ILogger<T>`, which is registered automatically by the framework defaults.

**ConsumeTextMessage.cs**

```cs
public class ConsumeTextMessage : IConsume<TextMessage>
{
    private readonly ILogger<ConsumeTextMessage> logger;

    public ConsumeTextMessage(ILogger<ConsumeTextMessage> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Consume(TextMessage message)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Wire up the auto subscriber (there's some leeway here as far as where/when to write/run this code).

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IBus>(RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost"));
}
```

**(Somewhere else, maybe `startup.Configure` or a `BackgroundService`)**

```cs
var subscriber = new AutoSubscriber(bus, "example");
subscriber.Subscribe(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Now, start the program and publish some messages, you should see every message end up in the default error queue.

```
System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance[T]()
   at EasyNetQ.AutoSubscribe.DefaultAutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher.DispatchAsync[TMessage,TAsyncConsumer](TMessage message)
   at EasyNetQ.Consumer.HandlerRunner.InvokeUserMessageHandlerInternalAsync(ConsumerExecutionContext context)
```

I know that I can provide my [own dispatcher](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Auto-Subscriber#using-an-ioc-container-with-autosubscriber), but how do we get that working with the ASP.NET Core services provider; ensuring that this works with scoped services?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, here's what I came up with.

```cs
public class MessageDispatcher : IAutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider provider;

    public MessageDispatcher(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public void Dispatch<TMessage, TConsumer>(TMessage message)
        where TMessage : class
        where TConsumer : class, IConsume<TMessage>
    {
        using(var scope = provider.CreateScope())
        {
            var consumer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TConsumer>();
            consumer.Consume(message);
        }
    }

    public async Task DispatchAsync<TMessage, TConsumer>(TMessage message)
        where TMessage : class
        where TConsumer : class, IConsumeAsync<TMessage>
    {
        using(var scope = provider.CreateScope())
        {
            var consumer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TConsumer>();
            await consumer.ConsumeAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of notable points...

The `IServiceProvider` dependency is the ASP.NET Core DI container. This may be unclear at first, because, throughout `Startup.ConfigureServices()`, you're registering types using the other interface, `IServiceCollection`.

```cs
public MessageDispatcher(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    this.provider = provider;
}
```

In order to resolve scoped services, you need to create and manage a scope's lifecycle *around* creating and using the consumer. And I'm using the `GetRequiredService<T>` extension method because I really want a nasty exception here and not a null reference that might leak for a while before we notice it (in the form of a null reference exception).

```cs
using(var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    var consumer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TConsumer>();
    consumer.Consume(message);
}
```

If you only used the `provider` directly, as in `provider.GetRequiredService<T>()`, you'd see an error like this when attempting to resolve a scoped consumer or a scoped dependency for a consumer.

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Example.Messages.ConsumeTextMessage' from root provider.'

In order to resolve scoped services and maintain *their* lifecycle properly for async consumers, you need to get the async/await keywords in the right place. You should await the `ConsumeAsync` call, which requires that the method be async. Use breakpoints on the await line and in your consumer and step line-by-line to get a better handle on this!

```cs
public async Task DispatchAsync<TMessage, TConsumer>(TMessage message)
    where TMessage : class
    where TConsumer : class, IConsumeAsync<TMessage>
{
    using(var scope = provider.CreateScope())
    {
        var consumer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TConsumer>();
        await consumer.ConsumeAsync(message);
    }
}
```

OK, now that we have the dispatcher, we just need to set everything up properly in Startup. We need to *resolve* the dispatcher from the provider so that the provider can provide itself properly. This is just *one* way of doing this.

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // messaging
    services.AddSingleton<IBus>(RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost"));
    services.AddSingleton<MessageDispatcher>();
    services.AddSingleton<AutoSubscriber>(provider =>
    {
        var subscriber = new AutoSubscriber(provider.GetRequiredService<IBus>(), "example")
        {
            AutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher = provider.GetRequiredService<MessageDispatcher>();
        }
    });

    // message handlers
    services.AddScoped<ConsumeTextMessage>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredServices<AutoSubscriber>().SubscribeAsync(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

Comment: I really like your answer. I can't however get this to work in after configuring an IHostBuilder (dotnet Console/Host app). The message Dispatch (and any consumer for that type) isnt called.
_builder.Services.GetRequiredService<AutoSubscriber>().SubscribeAsync(assembly);_
Any clue how to adapt?

Comment: Can I see more context? Maybe a Gist? https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Good tip! [Gist github](https://gist.github.com/davidzwa/be11ec614029d8689442830231bfd8c6)

Note I didnt test this code and removed code I cant show. Also note I tried both IConsumeAsync and IConsume (adjusting Program.cs accordingly).

Any tip or help would be awesome!

Comment: Ah also note: I do create and register IBus (although my code gist doesnt show). The error happens Runtime and when Dispatching the message. (It does trigger and notice that IConsume/Async is registered, it just cant construct the handler. Good to know: my service is a BackgroundService)

Answer (score 0):

I copied code from the above reply but it did not work for me. It causes issues with injected database contexts (scoped) reusing the same instance.

Just a small change:

Instead of:

```
using(var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    var consumer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TConsumer>();
    await consumer.ConsumeAsync(message);
}
```

In MessageDispatcher I needed to use **CreateAsyncScope** for the DispatchAsync method:

```
using(var scope = provider.CreateAsyncScope())
{
    var consumer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TConsumer>();
    await consumer.ConsumeAsync(message);
}
```