# AutoSubscriber in EasyNetQ does not working - RabbitMQ .NET

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, rabbitmq

Based on that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119753/how-to-write-an-easynetq-auto-subscriber-dispatcher-for-the-asp-net-core-service) I'm trying to create EasyNetQ Dispatcher for my messages. For some reason my Consumer is not triggered when my message appears in queue and I've no idea what the reason might be.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = LoadConfiguration();
        ConfigureServices(config);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IConfiguration LoadConfiguration()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        return builder.Build();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IConfiguration config)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(config)
                .AddEasyNetQ("host=127.0.0.1:5672;username=guest;password=guest")
                .AddSingleton<AutoSubscriber>(provider =>
                {
                    // When I put breakpoint below - is never reached. Is that correct behavior?
                    var subscriber = new AutoSubscriber(provider.GetRequiredService<IBus>(), "SomePrefix")
                    {
                        AutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher = provider.GetRequiredService<IAutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher>()
                    };
                    subscriber.Subscribe(new Assembly[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() });
                    subscriber.SubscribeAsync(new Assembly[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() });
                    return subscriber;
                });

        services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

Below is the rest of nested code, though it seems working fine - so probably the problem is in Program.cs

EasyNetQExtension

```
public static class EasyNetQExtension
    {
        private static void InternalInitEasyNetQ(IServiceCollection service, string rabbitMqConnection)
        {
            service.AddSingleton(RabbitHutch.CreateBus(rabbitMqConnection));
            service.AddSingleton<IAutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher, ConsumerMessageDispatcher>(serviceProvider => new ConsumerMessageDispatcher(serviceProvider));

            var consumerTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(x => x.IsClass && !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsInterface)
                .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(t => t.Name == typeof(IConsume<>).Name));
            foreach (var consumerType in consumerTypes)
            {
                service.AddTransient(consumerType);
            }
            
            // My consumer is found here, so this works properly
            var consumerAsyncTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(x => x.IsClass && !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsInterface)
                .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(t => t.Name == typeof(IConsumeAsync<>).Name));
            foreach (var consumerAsyncType in consumerAsyncTypes)
            {
                service.AddTransient(consumerAsyncType);
            }
        }

        public static IServiceCollection AddEasyNetQ(this IServiceCollection service, string rabbitMqConnectionString)
        {
            InternalInitEasyNetQ(service, rabbitMqConnectionString);

            return service;
        }
    }
```

ConsumerMessageDispatcher

```
public class ConsumerMessageDispatcher : IAutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public ConsumerMessageDispatcher(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public void Dispatch<TMessage, TConsumer>(TMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken()) where TMessage : class where TConsumer : class, IConsume<TMessage>
        {
            try
            {
                TConsumer consumer = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TConsumer>();
                consumer.Consume(message);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task DispatchAsync<TMessage, TConsumer>(TMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken()) where TMessage : class where TConsumer : class, IConsumeAsync<TMessage>
        {
            try
            {
                TConsumer consumer = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TConsumer>();
                await consumer.ConsumeAsync(message);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that by moving Autosubscriber to separate method so the correct looks:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = LoadConfiguration();
        var provider = ConfigureServices(config);

        ConfigureConsumers(provider);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IConfiguration LoadConfiguration()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        return builder.Build();
    }

    private static ServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>()
            .Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(options => configuration.GetSection("SendGridEmailSettings").Bind(options))
            .AddEasyNetQ(configuration["QueueConnectionData"]);

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    private static void ConfigureConsumers(ServiceProvider provider)
    {
        var autoSubscriber = new AutoSubscriber(provider.GetRequiredService<IBus>(), "SomePrefix")
        {
            AutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher = provider.GetRequiredService<IAutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher>()
        };

        autoSubscriber.Subscribe(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() });
        autoSubscriber.SubscribeAsync(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to implement `IConsumer<>` interface in your console app, so that it can be registered via `InternalInitEasyNetQ` method.

```cs
using EasyNetQ.AutoSubscribe;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class ConsumeTextMessage : IConsume<string>
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public ConsumeTextMessage(ILogger<ConsumeTextMessage> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void Consume(string message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Logging the message: " + message);
            Console.WriteLine("Reading the message: " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

Second, you are missing part where you write message using `IAutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher`. You can resolve `IAutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher` interface using `IServiceProvider` or dependency injection. Something along those lines:

```cs
var dispatcher = _provider.GetRequiredService<IAutoSubscriberMessageDispatcher>();
dispatcher.Dispatch<string, ConsumeTextMessage>("Dispatch my message - " + DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: You're saying that I have manually Dispatch my message? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Someone/something has to dispatch the message. In real life scenario it could be separate service. In sample application, yes - you have to send the message. And to implement consumers.

Comment: What will put the message in RabbitMQ?

Comment: Another service. Look before I was started playing with AutoSubscribe Dispatcher (so when I had manually defined subscribers) - everything was working fine. But now I want to improve it with modern solution which is AutoSubscribe to any new Consumer.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Understand now. Then just implement `IConsume<>` interface and adapt it to the type of message you're expecting, in case it's not `string`, like my example. You can omit 2nd part of my answer.

Comment: And if you try to dispatch message from the same app, as I described? Do you receive it then?

Comment: Then the issue is with correlation between the applications, or with message type you're sending from other application. But I think that would rather go in separate question. Here we solved problem on consumer side.

Comment: In my opinion it seems that there is still problem with `AutoSubscriber` part. Because like I said before, it was working without `AutoSubscriber`.

Comment: If `AutoSubscriber` would be a problem, message dispatched inside of the app would not work either. Since you said it works with internal `_dispatcher`, consumers are subscribed correctly. Are both apps pointing to the same queue? Do both apps read/write `string` type in the queue?

Comment: I figure out this. Check my answer.

Comment: So what was the issue exactly? To me, your first example worked as well when I add my consumer to the mix.

Comment: Look my answer. Previously code from `void ConfigureConsumers(ServiceProvider provider)` was in method `ConfigureServices(IConfiguration configuration)` inside `.AddSingleton<AutoSubscriber>(provider =>...` and it didn't work because of that. Honestly not sure why... Maybe `ServiceProvider` had to be build?